# SICP Exercise 1.2

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm having a hard time with exercise 1.2 in SICP.

Translate the following to prefix form:

```
5 + 4 + (2 - (3 - (6 + 4/5))) / 3(6 - 2)(2 - 7)
```

Here's what I have, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
(/
 (+
  (+ 4 5)
  (- 2
     (- 3
        (+ 6
           (/ 4 5)))))
 (* 3
    (*
     (-6 2)
     (- 2 7))))
```

Comment: in addition to the `(-6 2)` problem, there is also another problem in that the `5 + 4 + ...` should be outside (have lower precedence than) the `/`, but you put it inside

Comment: (+ 5 4
   (/ (- 2 (- 3 (+ 6 (/ 4 5))))
      (* 3 (- 6 2) (- 2 7))))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(-6 2)
```

Here you're trying to call `-6` with `2` as its argument, which doesn't work of course as `-6` is not a function. You rather want to call the `-` function with `6` and `2` as its arguments.

tl;dr: You forgot a space between `-` and `6`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(/ 
 (+ 5 4 (- 2 (- 3 (+ 6 (/ 4 5)))))
 (* 3 (- 6 2) (- 2 7)))
```